# Positioning ads on HTML5 game

Tags: html

I wana position a 300x50 banner ad at bottom of the screen.
Game scales to browser width and height.
So how to position the div such that its above 50px from bottom of the screen regradless game is played from mobile or tablet or desktop

Comment: Please include a question in your question!

Comment: Please share your efforts..

Answer (score 2):

```
.ad{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 50px;
}
```

That's it pretty much.

However, are there any research efforts by yourself? Before asking a question, you should at least seek for some information via google or the SO search. If you need a more complex and describing answer, please ask a more describing question.

Comment: <div id="pdms" style="position:absolute; bottom:50px; top:80%;margin-top:-125px;margin-left:-175px;width:350px;height:250px;">     This is my ad code any help here i dont know javascript much.

Comment: You don't need javascript for applying styles on an element

Comment: i got help close this thanks